# Close a file in vba after using Application.GetOpenFilename

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running analyses of reinforced concrete buildings in a software called OpenSees. The results of the analyses are written in txt files, so in order to analyse these results I read and write the txt files into Excel using a vba. There is no problem to write the data the first time.

My problem raises when after having the txt files written into Excel for the first time I try to run OpenSees a second time without closing Excel. Opensees points out that the txt files are opened and so it can not overwrite them. I supposed after using Close #1 the files were closed.

What I have to do so far is run OpenSees 1st time, use vba to write the results in Excel, save and close Excel, run OpenSees 2nd time, ... and so on.

The main code I am using to write the files is

```
ruta1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("text Files (*.out),*.out", MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsEmpty(ruta1) Then

    For i = LBound(ruta1) To UBound(ruta1)

        Open ruta1(i) For Input As #1

        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, linea
            valor = Split(linea, " ") ' valor(i) : 0 time - 1 Ux - 2 Uy - 3 Rz
            h5.Cells(f_elong + j, c_elong) = valor(1) / hw * 100
            h5.Cells(f_elong + j, c_elong + 1) = valor(2) / lw * 100
            h6.Cells(f_FD + j, c_FD) = valor(1) / hw * 100
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        Close #1

    Next

End If
```

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename` has nothing to do with it. It only retrieves and stores the file paths but doesn't actually open the file.

Comment: Thanks, I thought 'Application.GetOpenFilename' was the main function that opened the file.

Comment: @DeanOC I would like to know why you removed "thanks" from the end of the post, as well as the "Regards".

Comment: The use of Hi & Thanks (and all derivatives) are deemed to be clutter by StackOverflow and their usage is discouraged. Salutations such as Hi are removed automatically when a post is submitted, and the only reason Thanks isn't is that it is harder for SO to get the algorithm correct. This meta post will give you more info. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts   Personally, I see it as implicit that you will be thankful for any assistance. Hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that will fix your issue, but don't hard-code file numbers; use the `FreeFile` function instead, to let VBA give you a file number:

```
Dim fileNumber As Integer
fileNumber = FreeFile

Open ruta1(i) For Input As #fileNumber

Do Until EOF(fileNumber)
    Line Input #fileNumber, linea
   ...
Loop

Close #fileNumber
```

Also, you're dealing with external resources - there should be proper error handling here, with a cleanup subroutine that ensures all opened files are closed before the procedure exits:

```
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    ...

CleanExit:
    Close 'hammer: no file number closes all opened files
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: What is a FreeFile, I saw you define it as an integer... so is it like a special integer?
And, Where do I have to place "On Error ..."? After the code block I posted in the original post?
Thanks

Comment: `FreeFile` is a function defined in the VBA standard library, in the `VBA.FileSystem` module; as for `On Error`, it's usually the first executable line of code in any procedure I need to handle errors in ;-)

Comment: I included all your solutions, but I kept having the same problem. The way I solved this problem was I gave a "placebo" archive after the files I want are written, so the latest opened useful file is now free to be re-written by the next run. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with just using `#1` as file handler since you `Close` it after doing the processing. I can't really simulate why you're having issue in your code but you can give below a try to test if it will work for you. *Not a direct answer to your question, just a possible workaround.*

```
Dim ruta1 As Variant
ruta1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("text Files (*.out),*.out", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(ruta1) Then

    Dim linea, lines ' implicit Variant declaration

    For i = LBound(myTxt) To filecount
        Open myTxt(i) For Input As #1 ' Open the file
        ' Retrieve the lines of text and dump in an array
        lines = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbNewLine)
        Close #1 ' Close the file

        ' Work with the array instead of reading each line of the opened file
        Dim j As Long: j = 1 ' Or depending on what start value you require
        For Each linea In lines
            valor = Split(linea, " ") ' valor(i) : 0 time - 1 Ux - 2 Uy - 3 Rz
            h5.Cells(f_elong + j, c_elong) = valor(1) / hw * 100
            h5.Cells(f_elong + j, c_elong + 1) = valor(2) / lw * 100
            h6.Cells(f_FD + j, c_FD) = valor(1) / hw * 100
            j = j + 1
        Next
    Next

End If
```

Comment: It didn't work :-(. I think it has the same shortcoming as the previous one, it opens the txt files to read and write their contents in an array.

Additional information: OpenSees creates 3 folders with lots of txt files within them. At the beginning of the OpenSees(is an interpreter that uses tcl/tk) code I use 'file delete -force \folder'. OpenSees shows the error message when it tries to delete the last folder that was opened when vba wrote its content.